# Dynamic image height in recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I want to load images with dynamic height using Glide. I have an ImageView whose height is wrap_content and width is match_parent. When the recycler view loads the first time. The first image has a larger height than the rest of the images. My larger height image loads fine without any pixelation when I scroll down the view gets recycled and when I scroll back to top to first larger image it gets pixelated I think when the view gets recycled glide is using smaller recycler imageview height for downsampling the larger height image due to which its getting pixelated. I don't want to use setRecyclable (false) on recyclerview. Here's the implementation

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/drc_imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@color/OFF_WHITE" />
</LinearLayout>
```

For loading the image

```
GlideApp
                .with(context)
                .asBitmap()
                .fitCenter()
                .load(absoluteHomeList.get(position - 1).getDynamic_card_url())
                .into(holder.dynamicImageView);
```

Here are the images for reference
[image: In first image when is not recycled image is loading properly without pixelating]

[image: In second image i scrolled recycler view down and back to top the first image gets pixelated]

Comment: First of all it is very bad idea to use match-parent or wrap-content for both params when you use Glide. You need to calculate height and width of the image when gets downloaded. Glide gives callback for that. After that you set height and width to imageview (scaling may require if width of image is greater than device). This way you will have a fixed sized ImageView.

Comment: Your current problem occurs due to reusability of views in recyclerview. While scrolling same view is being used for another. To fix this you need to cache the scaled height/ width of image into respective modal class also.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Before loading image using glide use

```
holder.dynamicImageView.layout(0,0,0,0);
```

Comment: Can check [this](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1088#issuecomment-201214145) for reference.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/835#issuecomment-167438903) has a better explanation.